# Sums of converging limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I prove the property that if the sequences, $(x)\rightarrow x' $ and $(y)\rightarrow y'$ then $(x) + (y)\rightarrow x'+y'$

Comment: Do you know the epsilon definition of limits?

Comment: Yes, I know how to produce the proof now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.
Notice that $\{x_n\} \rightarrow x$ and $\{y_n\} \rightarrow y$ implies there exists $N_1,N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - x| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n > N_1$ and $|y_n - y| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n > N_2$. Let $N = max\{N_1,N_2\}$ then we have that $|x_n + y_n - (x+y)| = |(x_n - x) + (y_n - y)| \leq |x_n - x| + |y_n - y| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon $. As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we have by definition $\{x_n\} + \{y_n\} \rightarrow x+y$.

Comment: Your proof is very clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $|(x_n+y_n)-(x'+y')| \leq  |x_n-x'| + |y_n-y'|$